# What's the difference between cancelBubble and stopPropagation?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Can anyone please tell me difference in usage of `cancelBubble` and `stopPropagation` methods used in Javascript.

Comment: They're the same, except that `cancelBubble` is IE-only retardedness, and `stopPropagation` is standard.

Answer (score 63):

`cancelBubble` is an IE-only Boolean property (not method) that serves the same purpose as the `stopPropagation()` method of other browsers, which is to prevent the event from moving to its next target (known as "bubbling" when the event is travelling from inner to outer elements, which is the only way an event travels in IE < 9). IE 9 now supports `stopPropagation()` so `cancelBubble` will eventually become obsolete. In the meantime, the following is a cross-browser function to stop an event propagating:

```
function stopPropagation(evt) {
    if (typeof evt.stopPropagation == "function") {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        evt.cancelBubble = true;
    }
}
```

In an event handler function, you could use it as follows:

```
document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event; // For IE
    stopPropagation(evt);
};
```

Comment: Perhaps a minor thing, but if you are going to call `stopPropagation` as a function, is it not better to feature-test it as `== "function"` as opposed to `!= "undefined"`?

Comment: @ingredient_15939: The issue is that some methods of host objects in some browsers (mostly older versions of IE) do not return `"function"` from `typeof`. However, for the case of event objects, you're right, it's safe to assume that `stopPropagation`, if it exists, will return `"function"`.

Answer (score 10):

For compatibility with IE8 and older use `.cancelBubble` if `.stopPropagation()` is undefined:

```
if(ev.stopPropagation)ev.stopPropagation();
else ev.cancelBubble=true; // where ev is an event object
```

Read about in MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ff975961(v=vs.85)

Answer (score 4):

Another difference that anyone has described is that `e.cancelBubble` stops event propagation for the further elements only in bubbling phase (when event reaches the first bubbling element), while `.preventDefault()` prevent propagation both in capturing and bubbling phase (immediately for the next element in propagation).

```js
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var d = document.getElementById('d');

a.addEventListener('click',cancel,true);
b.addEventListener('click',cancel,true);
c.addEventListener('click',cancel,false);
d.addEventListener('click',cancel,false);


function cancel(event){
  var logElem = event.currentTarget.id;
  console.log(logElem);
  if(logElem==='a') event.cancelBubble = true;
  
}


var e = document.getElementById('e');
var f = document.getElementById('f');
var g = document.getElementById('g');
var h = document.getElementById('h');

e.addEventListener('click',stop,true);
f.addEventListener('click',stop,true);
g.addEventListener('click',stop,false);
h.addEventListener('click',stop,false);


function stop(event){
  var logElem = event.currentTarget.id;
  console.log(logElem);
  if(logElem==='e') event.stopPropagation();
  
}
```

```css
#a,#b,#c,#d,#e,#f,#g,#h{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:100%;
  height:90%;
  border:solid 1px #33aaff;
  padding:10px;
  padding-top:0px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#a,#e{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;

}
```

```html
<h3>cancelBubble</h3>
<div id='a'>a capturing
  <div id='b'>b capturing
    <div id='c'>c bubbling
      <div id='d'>d bubbling
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>stopPropagation</h3>
<div id='e'>e capturing
  <div id='f'>f capturing
    <div id='g'>g bubbling
      <div id='h'>h bubbling
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```