# Work with event.stopPropagation() on firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, stoppropagation

Why doesn't this code work for Firefox and IE? 
It's fine on chrome.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($(".contentIconDesk").hasClass('markIconDesk')) {           
        $(".contentIconDesk").removeClass('markIconDesk');          
        wndSelected = "";   
    }       
});

function markMe(icon, wnd) {
    event.stopPropagation();            
    if ($('#'+icon).hasClass('markIconDesk')) {
        $(".contentIconDesk").removeClass('markIconDesk');
        wndSelected = "";               
    } else {
        $(".contentIconDesk").removeClass('markIconDesk');
        $('#'+icon).addClass('markIconDesk');
        wndSelected = wnd;                  
    }       
};
```

The function `MarkMe();` is called in the event `onClick()` of some div in my HTML. The problem is with the `event.stopPropagation()`. When I click to add the class, the browser catch the click on `$(document)`.

If there is a good suggestion instead of using the code above, it will be great.

Comment: Post the HTML for the div you are using too..

Comment: You can get the initiator of the click event using event.target, see http://api.jquery.com/event.target/, for example `if ($(e.target).is("div")) return;` in your document click binding.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery and `onclick` event-handlers?

Comment: @DavidThomas I didn't find a way to obtain the parameters like this: `onclick="markMe($(this).attr('id'), 'stores');"` using the jQuery function: `$("#icon_1").click()`. Sorry, but I'm kind a newbie in js and jQuery. But I'm studying it hardly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this. For the div in your HTML, modify it like this:

```
<div id="something1" onclick="markMe('icon1', 'wnd1', event)">
<div id="something2" onclick="markMe('icon2', 'wnd2', event)">
<div id="something3" onclick="markMe('icon3', 'wnd3', event)">
```

And in your js use it like:

```
function markMe(icon, wnd, e) {

    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(".contentIconDesk").removeClass('markIconDesk');
    if ($('#' + icon).hasClass('markIconDesk')) {
        wndSelected = "";
    } else {
        $('#' + icon).addClass('markIconDesk');
        wndSelected = wnd;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

IE don't support stopPropagation method in it's DOM. You may use event.cancelBubble = true (I mean, cancelBubble property of the event object) instead. Have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596364/whats-the-difference-between-cancelbubble-and-stoppropogation)

Answer (score 1):

Because `event` is undefined in this piece of code:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: @DavidThomas - it wouldn't work.  It doesn't even make sense in that function. It belongs in the click handler, if anywhere. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass event as parameter of your `MarkMe` function

```
function markMe(icon, wnd, event) {
   event.stopPropagation(); 
   //...
}
```

Then when you call it, it should look like this :

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(e) {
    //...
    MarkMe(icon, wnd, e);
});
```

Comment: yeah, but using $('#myDiv').click(function(e), how whould I know in wich icon the user has clicked?