# How to stop event propagation in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Well, I know this question or similar one has been asked many time. But reading through them I'm still not able to fix the issue.

I have below code

```
    $('div#ItemCollection').on('click', function () {

        if ($('div#ListContainer').is(":visible")) {
            $('div#ListContainer').slideUp(400);
        }
        else {
            $('div#ListContainer').slideDown(400)
        }

     //What I have to write here to prevent event propagation
     //in IE8. Cause event.stopPropagation() does not work on IE8.
     //And which is also work on other browsers.
    })

$('body').click(function () {

    if ($('div#ListContainer').is(":visible")) {
        $('div#ListContainer').slideUp(400);
    }
    //Here as well
})
```

I use `$('body').click(function () {})` event to slide up the `div#ListContainer` when I click out side of it. Because `event.stopPropagation()` does not work in Internet Explorer 8 the `div` is just opening and closing.

Comment: *"event.stopPropagation()"* works in IE8, something is with your code. Create a demo then someone might help. Otherwise answer to your current question is "To prevent event bubbling - use event.stopPropagation()".

Comment: @dfsq: To clarify, _"event.stopPropagation()"_ only works in IE8 if the _event_ object is a jQuery object. The normal Javascript  _"event.stopPropagation()"_ only works in IE9+.
Documentation: [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Answer (score 3):

Try it again by using an event parameter within your event handler function, e.g.

```
$('body').click(function (event) { ...
```

If `event.stopPropagation()` is undefined, you can use the IE only property `cancelBubble` to prevent the event from moving to its next target. Take care, `cancelBubble` is deprecated, use it only for IE8 and older:

```
if(event.stopPropagation)
    event.stopPropagation();
else
    event.cancelBubble=true;
```

Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7596364/5346109) and the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms533545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yep, `cancelBubble` works. It is 2019, and yes, there are still places that use IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
$('div#ItemCollection').on('click', function (e) { // add e var here
    if ($('div#ListContainer').is(":visible")) {
        $('div#ListContainer').slideUp(400);
    }
    else {
        $('div#ListContainer').slideDown(400)
    }
    e.stopPropagation(); // e is a jQuery object that does magic to work in IE8
})

$('body').click(function () {
    if ($('div#ListContainer').is(":visible")) {
        $('div#ListContainer').slideUp(400);
    }
    // Nothing needed here
})
```

Note that `event.stopPropagation()` only works in IE8 if the `event` object is a jQuery object. The normal Javascript  `event.stopPropagation()` only works in IE9+.