# How to exclude numbers from entry on IE11?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11

Before IE 11 you could put a zero in keycode if you didn't want the character to be entered.

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeypress="ValidateText();">    
</asp:TextBox>

function ValidateText() {
    if (!((window.event.keyCode < 48 || window.event.keyCode > 57) && window.event.keyCode != 46)) {
        window.event.keyCode = 0;
    }
```

This worked on IE 10 but not on IE 11.

Comment: Can you cancel bubbling? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533545(v=vs.85).aspx I think that might be IE-only; see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7596403/424129

Comment: You should probably look at how [DOM event handlers work, cross-browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers). IE11 (and its follow up, the Edge browser) work much more like other browsers in terms of DOM Events. I can give you an answer to this specific question, but I think you'll be better served by learning more about the subject.

Comment: Placing the *event object* on `window` was an older approach. For years Internet Explorer has passed the *event object* to the handler, like all other major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `window.event` is an antiquated way of getting the event in an event handler. It's better to pass the event to the handler like this:

```
onkeypress="return ValidateText(event);"
```

Note that `return`; that's going to help later.

In your event handler, you will now have the event passed in as an argument. Also, know that returning `false` from an event handler cancels the event.

```
function ValidateText(event) {
    return event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 || event.keyCode === 46;
}
```

Now we can just return whether the key pressed was not a number.

Comment: Thank you Mike. What a nice and simple solution. I did make some changes and it is just what I needed.

Comment: Glad it helped! One thing you can do to thank me is to "upvote" the answer by clicking on the up arrow, and/or accepting the answer, which is the checkmark below the down arrow. See [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.