# Input field behind a tag requires double click to focus on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Imagine this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awoXKv

As you can see, I got an input field inside my a element. (This cannot be changed currently). What I want to do, that when I click the input, the input gets focused and I don't get redirected.

The above snippet does exactly this in Chrome/Firefox. But now, I tested it on IE and am experiencing an issue, that the input only gets focused, if I use double click.

I tried to focus it manually by using this `$(e.currentTarget).find('input').focus();`, but this didn't help. Som eother StackOverflow thread said, this is because IE lazy loads the events and I have to use a timeout fucntion

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input').focus();
}, 100);
```

But even this didn't work. How can I focus an input behind an a tag in IE?

*Update*:
Doesn't seem like a focus problem, because when I use `alert($(e.currentTarget).find('input').is(':focus'));` it returns true. What else could be the problem here?

Comment: events Bubble, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596364/whats-the-difference-between-cancelbubble-and-stoppropagation, but your codepen still does not work because of the nested input in an a element... I don't think that it is valid html.... it doesn't make sense to nest an input element inside a hyperlink..... the common design pattern is to nest input elements in form elements.

Comment: You are right, this wasn't valid HTML. We changed our structure and now it works. I'm fairly new to HTML (mostly developing PHP), so I didn't know that after a friend told me and I used the w3c validator

Comment: thanks for the feedback, it is understandable in your situation (coming from a server side web development). The w3c validators will help you get up to speed with an understanding syntax of markup (html) and use/reuse of COMMON DESIGN PATTERNS... you could probably think of a web browser as an interpreter.... what comes down the wire (html source) has not been compiled (like an exe) and may contain syntax or logic errors is  parsed and transposed into the DOM where it can be manipulated with javascript....html5 is the first specification that defines the error correction rules for markup.