# JS: is event.cancelBubble a method or boolean

Tags: javascript

As per w3schools [cancelBubble](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_cancelbubble.asp) is a method but in the example on the same page,

```
function func1(event) {
  alert("DIV 1");
  event.cancelBubble = true;
}
```

it's used as a boolean property. Can some clarify what actually is cancelBubble, a method or property.

Thanks

Comment: According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelBubble) **cancelBubble** is a property

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596364/whats-the-difference-between-cancelbubble-and-stoppropagation has a detailed answer if you are interested in.